# CSS Make flexbox-rows even hight (like in table) with wrapping

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, css-grid

I want to have card-like items with the same height arranged like a table, but with the ability to wrap to the next line. The rows in each card should have the same height as in the neighbour-card.

Here is a demo-code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 33%;
  div {
    color: blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div>1st</div>
    <div>2nd</div>
    <div>3rd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>1st</div>
    <div>2nd this is more<br>text here<br>and even more<br>text</div>
    <div>3rd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Here is most<br>of the text in the first row</div>
    <div>2nd</div>
    <div>3rd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Overflow! This should be in the next row</div>
    <div>2nd</div>
    <div>3rd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/86bondmy/7/

The idea is that the 1st row in the 1st card should have the same height as the 1st row in the 2nd and 3rd card. And the 2nd row in the 1st card should have the same height as the 2nd row in the 2nd and 3rd card. etc.

The problem is: The text in the cards are not predictable, so it might be that in 2nd card the 2nd row might be the biggest, while in the 3rd card the 1st row might contain the most text, etc.

Any idea how to solve this? Is it possible with flexbox or should I use gridview or a table?

Comment: No, that won't be possible with flexbox.

Comment: Thanks. But how can it be achived? Table and gridview aren't able to handle the wrap of the cards (which is needed for responsive design), or am I wrong here?

Comment: The grid layout is probably  what you need . Repeat, auto-fill, minmax() , auto-rows ,... take à look at https://gridbyexample.com/examples/  and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: That might be possible with css flexbox, I think they should have the same parent, if you want them to be treated equally, then align content: stretch, and flex wrap: wrap should do the rest